# What access specifier must be used for UserControl members when used with the WinForms Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I created a larger UserControl and added it with Forms Designer to a form.

The application compiles and runs fine, until I edit something in the designer.

Then in InitializeComponent the

```
this.myUserControl = new MyUserControl();
```

line vanishes.
The user control itself gets declared and initialized. The problem is, that the instance creation is missing and when it comes to the initialization I get a NullReferenceException.

I have to add that I didn't touch the designer for a few weeks. During that time I changed a lot of public fields of my UserControl to internal or private. Everything worked fine until I tried to edit the form that contains my UserControl.

When I found the missing instantiation I took a backup and changed every membervariable of my UserControl back to public and the problem with the missing instantiation is fixed again.

Are there any known problems/restrictions according access specifiers used in Windows Forms UserControls when they are used in the designer?

Comment: A workaround would be to move the code in the Form.designer.cs file to your Form.cs file. Then, if the `MyUserControl` resides in the same solution and not a dll you are referencing, even your toolbox user control reference will get updated whenever you modify your user control.

Comment: One well known restriction is that it must be able to display itself, so all paint code must work independently from any initialization code. That is probably not the cause of your problem. Were those fields part of a constructor?